# How to root Micromax Canvas HD A116 device running Android 4.2.1?

Tags: rooting, 4.2-jelly-bean, android-versions

I have never rooted a phone before & did some primary search on xda forums for Micromax Canvas HD A116. 
I found a [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2167621) to root the phone but the steps listed on it are a little incomprehensible to me.

Can anyone please provide a detailed step by step procedure to root my device from the xda forum link or your own method in simple, specific steps?

My phone is running Android 4.2.1. If any other information is needed about my phone, please leave a comment.

Comment: Have you tried rooting it the way [TechxcyT shows](http://www.techxcyt.com/2013/07/root-micromax-canvas-hd-a116-with-421_15.html)?

Comment: The link shows rooting with [Motochopper Root Tool](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=22946563261203713).

Answer (score 1):

You can root it easily by using the Framaroot application. Here is a link to the XDA thread, where you can find more information on the app http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/root-framaroot-one-click-apk-to-root-t2130276

Comment: Thanks, but could you post ([edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/108297/edit)) the steps for how to use Framaroot as well. In case the link goes down and the reader managed to download the `.apk` from some other source, the steps would prove to be  helpful.